# Why does the image name change between Mysql and Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a problem which is that the image name in Mysql post *featured* field  is : "/uploads/posts/img1.jpg" .but when I retrieve the image name from Laravel with the following statement:
$image_path = $post->featured , I get a full url "http://127.0.0.1:8000/uploads/posts/img1.jpg" .
I need the result to be in the database format to be able to delete the image.

Please help.

Comment: Can you provide the Post.php file?

Comment: Update `public function getFeaturedAttribute($featured)` to `public function getFeaturedAttribute()`

Comment: I have the following function in Post.php: public function getFeaturedAttribute($featured){
        return asset($featured);
    } what do u suggest ?

Comment: Replace `asset($featured);`,by `asset($this->featured);`

Answer (score 0):

When you just echo $image_path, what did you get?

If you use `asset($image_path)`, it will put the full URL.

If you only want to get the path, use `{{ $image_path }}` or directly `{{ $post->featured }}`